# ATDD vs Integration Tests

Tags: integration-testing, atdd

It is my understanding that ATDD is from the QC/QA perspective and test the over all process. This testing of an over all process, how the different modules integrate, sounds like the definition of a  integration test. How does Acceptance Test Driven Development differ from Integration Tests? Or are they synonymous?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of ATDD is incorrect. You have indeed described integration tests not ATDD.

Have a read of the following snippet from this [link](http://testobsessed.com/2008/12/acceptance-test-driven-development-atdd-an-overview/)

> Acceptance Test Driven Development (ATDD) is a practice in which the whole team collaboratively discusses acceptance criteria, with examples, and then distills them into a set of concrete acceptance tests before development begins. It’s the best way I know to ensure that we all have the same shared understanding of what it is we’re actually building. It’s also the best way I know to ensure we have a shared definition of Done.

In practice you have your clients, Dev's, QA all in one room and you discuss a particular feature. The customer describes the new functionality and it is distilled into a number of acceptance tests.

There are various ATDD frameworks(JBehave, Cucumber, spec flow etc) which you can use to automate these tests and run them against your code. Most make use of a common language such as gherkin which takes the form of GIVEN, WHEN, THEN.

For example:

```
Scenario: Simple Addition
Given a calculator I just turned on
When I add 4 and 5
Then the result is 9
```

Within these frameworks we setup steps that map to each line of this example. One for setting up a calculator, one for addition and one for asserting the expected value matches the actual value. Obviously these can be more complex.

This gives us a test failure until the feature has been implemented to the specification everyone has agreed to. When the tests pass the feature is complete.